# JaCoCo issue with Weblogic

Tags: weblogic, jacoco

I am trying to find the code coverage (Not Test Cases) via JaCoCo on Weblogic

Below entry I gave under server -> server start arugment. I can see .exec file is generated at desired location but for every class it's coming as 0 %. Though I'm able to test the same with Windows + Tomcat its is working but I'm getting issue with weblogic on Linux box.

> -javaagent:/apps/dev4/deploy/code-coverage/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/apps/dev4/deploy/code-coverage/jacoco.exec,append=false,includes=*

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Check whether the JAVA Options are set or not.
2. Exclude those class files whose methods exceed the 64k limit.
3. Check the jvm version.